# C#, treeview, multi-colo(u)red treenode text

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I change a color of some part of treenode Text ?

For example,

first symbol is red,
last symbols are yellow ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the [DrawMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.drawmode.aspx) property on the TreeNode to [OwnerDrawText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeviewdrawmode.aspx) and handle the [DrawNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.drawnode.aspx) event yourself.

Keep in mind though, that drawing the first glyph and the rest separately may cause unexpected results with complex scripts or diacritics.